# Document AI Credentials on production

Tags: .net, deployment, credentials, webapi, cloud-document-ai

Im working with document AI google service. And so far ive been using credentials from json file i generated throughout console. What could be the reason why its not working on live version.

-Tried to get google refresh token somehow

Comment: Can you provide more details about what is not working? Are you getting a specific error message? Do you have other Google Cloud services that are using the Service Account authentication method?